# Route angular 2 and laravel 5.3 errors

Tags: angular, laravel-5, routes

I build a laravel 5.3 project and I'm inserting angular 2 to manage the front-end. I had several modules, e.g. companies.
The route /companies load a page with all companies ( companies index )

```
=> localhost:8000/companies ...
```

In this view, I load the `app.component` and start the angular 2 to routing a company in a single page `companies.blade.php`. It loads everything OK and works, but an error appears:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes:
>   'companies'

And it does not appear in the laravel route, staying only: localhost:8000.
(I think because it loads angular 2 routing )

How can I proceed? 
obs: Sorry my english

Comment: This question was Solved

Comment: Would you please tell us how was it solved ?